# How to address "Could not create status list error" from Github Mac app?

Tags: github-for-mac

If you run into the error "Could not create status list error" while syncing a branch using the Github Mac app here is a solution

Solution: There are nested folder paths in your file path (in my case it was under the cocoa pods folder). Deleting the top level folder fixed the issue.

Comment: You should update this post to be phrased like a question and provide the answer yourself: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

The OP's solution does not work for me. I get the "Could not create status list." error on repositories that do and do not contain folders.